# Specify model name in Sequelize where function

Tags: sequelize.js

Looking at the below code:

```
sequelize.where(
  sequelize.col('"organisations->organisation_users"."roleId"'),
  sequelize.col('"organisations->roles"."id"'),
),
```

How would I do something like:

```
sequelize.where(
   sequelize.col(organisation_users.roleId),
   sequelize.col(organisations.id),
),
```

The whole query:

```
context.params.sequelize = {
    raw: false,
    include: [{
      model: organisations,
      where: organisationId ? { id: organisationId } : {},
      include: [{
        model: roles,
        where: roleId ? { id: roleId } : {},
      }],
    }],
    where: single ? (
      sequelize.and(
        sequelize.where(
          sequelize.col('"organisations->organisation_users"."roleId"'),
          sequelize.col('"organisations->roles"."id"'),
        ),
        sequelize.where(
          sequelize.col('"organisations->organisation_users"."userId"'),
          sequelize.col("users.id")
        )
      )
    ) : {}
  }
```

Essentially, that I let the model do the mapping and not have me write out the string. The string way works at the moment but is also less maintainable.

*Keeping in mind that I have queries that use the above code that help with pagination, I believe there is some code in sequelize which can cause issues when you pass in limit and the such*

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you & Regards,

Emir

Comment: Post whole query.

Comment: @VivekDoshi Done!